# Check Specfic row with multiple rows in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select users list who is status is disabled for all application in username(ur_username table and that users should be active in Person Table(ur_person).

I tried with the following query :

```
 select distinct E.PERSON_ID , E.DOMAIN_ID,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.type,E.username, E.SYSTEM_name  from  
(SELECT  distinct p.person_id,p.domain_id,p.first_name,p.last_name,p.type,u.username, U.STATUS, U.SYSTEM_ID,s.system_name from ur_username u join
ur_username_person up on u.username_id=up.username_id 
join ur_person p on up.person_id=p.person_id join ur_system s on u.system_id=s.system_id 
 WHERE p.status='ACTIVE') E WHERE E.person_id IN 
  ( select distinct P.PERSON_ID from ur_username u join  ur_username_person up on u.username_id=up.username_id 
    join ur_person p on up.person_id=p.person_id 
   where u.status='DISABLED')
```

I need to get the person list who is status is Disabled in all system in username Table as below image:

But instead I am getting person who is disable in one system but active in some other systems also:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `person_id`s using aggregation and `having`:

```
select p.person_id
from ur_username u join
     ur_username_person up
     on u.username_id = up.username_id join
     ur_person p join
     ur_system s
     on u.system_id = s.system_id 
where p.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by p.person_id
having max(u.status) = min(u.status) and max(u.status) ='DISABLED';
```

You specify that you want the persons, so this seems to answer your question.  You can easily enhance this query to return more columns.